# cURL fails to login in to my router

Tags: curl

I wanted to port my reconnect script from `iMacros` to `curl`. `iMacros` was great because it acts like regular web browser and you can record your actions and then edit the code, but i'd like to port it to curl in order to use same code on `rasbian`. 
Here is the `iMacros` code:

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://192.168.1.1/
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 20
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=TXT:Wyloguj<SP>się
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=YOUR_USERNAME
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=NAME:password_* CONTENT=YOUR_PASSWORD
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=ID:center_login_submit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=SRC:http://192.168.1.1/images/rg_box.png
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=TXT:Połączenia<SP>sieciowe
TAG POS=15 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=SRC:http://192.168.1.1/images/edit.png
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=ID:center_conn_disable_ppp1
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=ID:center_confirm_submit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=ID:center_conn_enable_ppp1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:form_contents ATTR=TXT:Wyloguj<SP>się
```

I tried to log in by using

```
curl -c cookie -b cookie -d "username=admin&password_*=admin" --location http://192.168.1.1
```

but it fails,url it returns is

> "http://192.168.1.1:80/index.cgi?host%5fmac=my_mac_address&page=
>   **page%5fcookies%5fdisabled%** 5ferror&req%5fmode=0&strip%5fpage%5ftop=0&strip%5fpage%5ftabs=0&strip%5fpage%5flogo=0&scroll%5ftop=0&page%5fsession%5fid=&button%5fvalue="

I heard this router have ridiculous protections in `webui`, or maybe I just forgot about some value in command?

ps. I hope cURL supports random variables since the form id in login page have ALWAYS different name in form of `password_randomNumbersAndLetters`. Because of that I used "`password_*`"

edit: here is [login page in english](http://pastebin.com/FWKsjE09)

Comment: Could you [paste](http://pastebin.com/) the source code of the login page and reply with the link? It would also help if you would send the URL that pops up once you actually navigate to `192.168.1.1` (maybe  `192.168.1.1/index.cgi`? I'm just speculating the URL that you included in the post).

Comment: @Coder256 Here is Login page: [link](http://pastebin.com/vLHQd87y) it uses index.cgi as a main file (it only appears after log in but you can go to /192.168.1.1/index.cgi and it works too) and the address after logging in is: `http://192.168.1.1/index.cgi?host_mac=youknowwhatishere&page=page_home&prev_page=page_login&has_param=1&req_mode=0&mimic_button_field=submit_button_login_submit%3a+%2e%2e&strip_page_top=0&strip_page_tabs=0&strip_page_logo=0&scroll_top=0&page_session_id=alsoyouknowwhatishere&button_value=' `

Comment: Could you upload the English version, please? And also the URL of the login page itself before logging in. The router model and brand might also be useful.

Comment: [english login page](http://pastebin.com/FWKsjE09). Before logging in url is simply router address (http://192.168.1.1) but since index.cgi is main file it also works (http://192.168.1.1/index.cgi) . Router model and brand is Netiaspot-1 manufactured by Netia (it is Netia internet provider original router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That router page looks really complicated. If I were you, I would go with [iMacros for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en) or [iMacros for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), both of which are compatible with Raspbian. Just record a phony macro, right click on it, select "Edit Macro", then paste in the macro you have.

Comment: that's a shame, I wanted to learn how to use cURL that way (+ configure it with jdownloader2). Anyway thanks for the tip!